# Natural morphism of sheaves $pr_1^{-1} F \otimes pr_2^{-1}G \rightarrow j_*(F\otimes G)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, category-theory

I am reading a book, and the book said there is a natural map, which I don't know how. Can someone help me please? I can try to define the map, but it will be complicated, using sheafification many times.

Let F, G be sheaves of abelian groups on X. Let $K = pr_1^{-1} F \otimes pr_2^{-1}G$ be a sheaf on $X\times X$, where $pr_1, pr_2$ are two projections. Let $j: X\rightarrow X\times X$ be the diagonal map, then the book said there is a natural map:

$K\rightarrow j_{*} (F\otimes G)$

Comment: Maybe a little context could help; tell us which book, page, etc. For the time being, you should look at something like "projection formula" for the external tensor product of sheaves

Comment: It's Voisin's Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I, page 131, equation (5.7)

Comment: Note that $j^{-1}K = j^{-1}pr_1^{-1}F \otimes j^{-1}pr_2^{-1}G$. But $j^{-1}pr_i^{-1} = (pr_i \circ j)^{-1} = Id$ for $i=1,2$. Therefore, you have a natural isomorphism $j^{-1}K \rightarrow F \otimes G$. Since $j^{-1}$ is adjoint to $j_*$, this gives Voisin's natural map.

Comment: @Cass, yes, thank you.

Comment: @Cass: This is an answer, right? Not a comment.